# page getting rendered after restrict drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am using a custom module to restrict a role to a url in drupal 7 the code is as follows:

```
 <?php

 // Implements hook_init() 
 function restrict_access_init() {
   $restrictions = restrict_access_restrictions();
   global $user;
   foreach ($restrictions as $path => $roles) {
     // See if the current path matches any of the patterns provided.
     if (drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], $path)) {
       // It matches, check the current user has any of the required roles
       $valid = FALSE;
       foreach ($roles as $role) {
             print implode("','",$user ->roles);
         if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
           $valid = TRUE;
           break;
         }
       }

       if (!$valid) {
         drupal_access_denied();
       }
     }
   }
 }

 function restrict_access_restrictions() {
   // This array will be keyed by path and contain an array of allowed roles for that path
   return array(
     'path/path' => array('admin'),
   );
 }

 ?>
```

This does restrict access just fine but it then renders the page un-styled after the footer.

Any ideas why this may be happening?
I'm at a lost end with this now.

Comment: ive found the answer, i needed to add module_invoke_all('exit');
exit(); under drupal_acess_denied();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to add module_invoke_all('exit'); exit(); under drupal_acess_denied();

e.g.

```
 drupal_acess_denied(); 
 module_invoke_all('exit');
 exit();
```